# Include Kotlin/Native KDocs documentation in built .frameworks for iOS/XCode

Tags: kotlin, ios-frameworks, kotlin-native, kotlin-interop, kdoc

I'm developing a Kotlin/Native library for both iOS and Android.

When running `./gradlew assemble` I get the release/debug `.framework`s with Obj-C Headers.

I can use these `.framework`s fine. But I would also like to carry on with documentation of classes and functions when using the code on XCode.

If I use KDoc and document my code:

```kotlin
/**
 * This is a comment about the class I developed.
 * [BaseService] is a class.
 */
class BaseService {

    /**
     * Comments about this val
     */
    val greeting = "Hello"

    /**
     * This function greets the user
     */
    fun greetUser(){
        println(greeting)
    }

}
```

All of this is lost when bringing it to my iOS project. Because the `.framework`s don't carry the KDocs with it.

Is there any way to carry the documentation over to the Obj-C Headers or other auxiliary files when assembling the `.framework` files? Maybe some Gradle configuration I am missing?

Comment: Yeah that would be helpful indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pre-made option for this, you can upvote an issue [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/4000).

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your module's build.gradle.kts as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#export-of-kdoc-comments-to-generated-objective-c-headers):

```
kotlin {
    targets.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget> {
        compilations.get("main").compilerOptions.options.freeCompilerArgs.add("-Xexport-kdoc")
    }
}
```

This enables the ability to export KDoc comments to generated Objective-C headers.